# JPA Biderecional relation

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-one, bidirectional

I am trying to create a relational 1-to-1 between User Table and Code Table.

1 User can have 1 code but it's not mandatory.

Code class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "codes")
public class Code  {
     ...

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
    ...
}
```

User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    ...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Code code;
}
```

**Flows:**

When I create a Code, I provide a user and it will add automatically the User ID into Code table **BUT** the User table keeps the code column empty.

**Problem:**
I am doing something wrong here? I was expecting that when I create a code, the User table also updates with PIN code.

Comment: show the codes that how you configure the relationship between `Code` and `User`

Answer (score 0):

The owner is User. The User controls the relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "codes")
public class Code  {
     ...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "code", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    ...
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Code code;
}
```